# Why do we instantiate Calendar Class(abstract) in Java

Tags: java, oop, static

I am a beginner Java programmer, and I've been reading about the Calendar class. It's an abstract class and all of its methods are static, but it is used as follows:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Where you use `cal` to call methods like:

```
cal.setTimeinMillis(day1);
```

I'm confused about this. When calling methods against a class, why do we need a reference variable and **how is this legal for static methods?**

Comment: the Calender class uses the [Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) that is where the `getInstance()` is derived from.  This allows you to get an instance reference to `Calender` statically allowing you to use the instance (non-static) methods.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Is not calling a constructor, it's just calling a (static) method that returns an instance of some subclass (of `Calendar`).

Answer (score 2):

Take another look at [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html); most of the methods of Calendar that do anything interesting (other than the getInstance() methods) are not static and require an instance (which is indeed the container of the moment in time that the calendar represents).

Answer (score 2):

1) Is Calendar not Calandar

2) `Calendar.getInstance()` will return some concrete implementation of calendar, probably `GregorianCalendar`.

3) [cal.setTimeinMillis(day1);](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setTimeInMillis%28long%29) is object method, not static.

Answer (score 1):

setTimeInMillis() is not static.  The reason you need to call a getInstance() method to return an instance is that there are several getInstance() methods, and you can call them for different time zones and/or different locales than the default.  Which time zone or locale you choose has an impact on how the other methods work.